# MySQL LIKE statement error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, sql-like

in my query I'm using LIKE statement and this is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ogloszenia WHERE oferta = "Oferta kupna" and LIKE = "cokolwiek" ORDER BY id DESC Limit 5 offset 0;
```

And I'm getting error like this:

```
Something is wrong in your syntax near 'LIKE = "cokolwiek" ORDER BY id DESC Limit 5 offset 0' in line 1
```

Can you tell me how to fix it or what is an issue of this problem?

Thank you anyway.

Comment: In addition to the answers already given: Unless you put at least one `%` character in there, LIKE will do the same comparison as `=`.

Comment: @CBroe It is true for ms sql for instance but not for mysql. Look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 3):

You should not have an equal sign after the LIKE operator and it should be related to a column

```
somecolumn LIKE 'cokolwiek'
```

For LIKE to make any difference over an equal sign add wildcards `%` and `_` to the string.

IE:

```
somecolumn LIKE '%cokolwiek%'
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

(also changed to single quotes for good practise)

Comment: Should it be single quotes? Also may want to give them some examples on how the LIKE operator works. IE, it's kind of pointless for them to search 'cokolwiek'

Comment: Yes I always use single quotes, but might be irrelevant for this error. According to the manual it seem possible to use both? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes, not double quotes. You also shouldn't have an `=` near LIKE, and need to specify a column name near `LIKE`. This would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM ogloszenia WHERE oferta = 'Oferta kupna' AND columnname LIKE 'cokolwiek' ORDER BY id DESC Limit 5 offset 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like is already operator, you don't need to use `=`

```
LIKE `cokolwiek`
```

To get advantage of `LIKE` you can use wildcard characters.